# Block Multiple file selection and upload in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to upload files in my application using Angular 4. I am able to upload single file as well as multiple file. But I have to block, when user is trying to browse and upload second file.

In short, Only one file can be uploaded, if they try to upload another file they should get a pop up or something.

Please help in achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **change** event to pass the input file element to your function.

```
<input ng-model="photo" (change)="onChange($event)" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

In function

```
 onChange($event: any) {

    if($event.target.files.length > 1){
      alert("select only one file at a time...");
      return;
   }else{
     // Do your other stuff...
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not recognizing "$" symbol in ts file. Do I have to add any import statement?

Comment: @SachinShah It's for AngularJs not for Angular 2 +

Comment: im using angular 4

Comment: @RKM I have update my answer as per angular 4 version supported code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for input's **change** event and fire a function and check

`<input (change)="myUploader($event)" multiple type="file" accept="image/*" />`

```
 myUploader($event: any) {
    if ($event.target.files.length > 2) {
      console.log('limit reached')
      return false;
    } else if ($event && $event.target.files.length) {
      // Your code
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

<input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" type="file" multiple accept=".xlsx"
(change)="onFileSelect($event.target.files)" />

In this case just remove **multiple** attribute from tag, It will does not allow user to select multiple files.